# Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'completed') in Vue 3

Tags: vue.js, axios, vuejs3

I'm trying to create Todo List App with Laravel and Vue.js.
I have problem with that title error.
I've watched this video (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UHSipe7pSac&t=2482s) for paractcing
And also, I've done until 47:50, but when I wrote a a code listItem.vue, It didn't work as shown in video.
Although I compared with mycode for many times, I couldn't where is wrong.
If you have solution, Please tell me how to fix.
And, What is best way how to debug apps with laravel and Vue.js?
Here is my version
php
7.3.11
vue
vue@3.2.31

listItem.vue

```html
<template>
  <div class="item">
    <input type="checkbox" @change="updateCheck()" v-model="item.completed" />
    <span>{{ item.name }}</span>
    <button @click="removeItem()" class="trashcan">
      <font-awesome-icon icon="trash" />
    </button>
  </div>
</template>
<script>
export default {
  props: ["item"],
};
</script>

<style scoped>
.completed {
  text-decoration: line-through;
  color: #999999;
}
.itemTexgt {
  width: 100%;
  margin-left: 20px;
}
.item {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
.trashcan {
  background: #e6e6e6;
  border: none;
  color: #ff0000;
  outline: none;
}
</style>
```

app.vue

```html
<template>
  <div class="todoListContainer">
    <div class="heading">
      <h2 id="title">TodoList</h2>
      <add-item-form />
    </div>
    <list-view :items="items" />
  </div>
</template>
<script>
import addItemForm from "./addItemForm.vue";
import listView from "./listView.vue";
export default {
  components: {
    addItemForm,
    listView,
  },
  data: function () {
    return {
      items: [],
    };
  },
  methods: {
    getList() {
      axios
        .get("api/items")
        .then((response) => {
          this.items = response.data;
        })
        .catch((error) => {
          console.log(error);
        });
    },
  },
  created() {
    this.getList();
  },
};
</script>

<style scoped>
.todoListContainer {
  width: 350px;
  margin: auto;
}

.heading {
  background: #e6e6e6;
  padding: 10px;
}

#title {
  text-align: center;
}
</style>
```

error.log

```js
app.js:34649 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'completed')
    at Proxy.render (app.js:34649:69)
    at renderComponentRoot (app.js:22841:44)
    at ReactiveEffect.componentUpdateFn [as fn] (app.js:26958:57)
    at ReactiveEffect.run (app.js:20778:25)
    at setupRenderEffect (app.js:27084:9)
    at mountComponent (app.js:26867:9)
    at processComponent (app.js:26825:17)
    at patch (app.js:26426:21)
    at mountChildren (app.js:26613:13)
    at mountElement (app.js:26522:17)
```

postscript
listView.vue

```
<template>
  <div>
    <div v-for="(item, index) in items" :key="index"></div>
    <list-item :item="item" class="item" />
  </div>
</template>
<script>
import listItem from "./listItem.vue";
export default {
  props: ["items"],
  components: {
    listItem,
  },
};
</script>

<style scoped>
.item {
  background: #e6e6e6;
  padding: 5px;
  margin-top: 5px;
}
</style>
```

I learned and understood listItem.vue's parent is listView.vue.

Comment: I suspect it's because your child component is created before your parent component, and since `items` is empty, your child component will throw the error. You could add a boolean status in your parent component. When the data is loaded, the child component will be shown.

Comment: Your declaration of the prop `"item"` could be more helpful if you add a "type" to it. Considering you're looking for `item.completed` you can do: `props : {item:{ type:Object }}`. This tells Vue you're expecting that prop as an object and the runtime error will be more specific and maybe help with debugging.

Comment: @wittgenstein  
Thank you for your comment.
From my research, I too thought you were correct in your prediction.
However, I have not been able to find out where in the parent component I can set the boolean type so that the parent component is loaded first.
Do you mean somewhere in app.vue?

Comment: @slowFooMovement  
Thank you for your comment.
I tried but, no particular changes occurred on the console.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What a silly mistake I had made!

```
<template>
  <div>
    <div v-for="(item, index) in items" :key="index"></div>
    <list-item :item="item" class="item" />
  </div>
</template>
```

↓

```
<div v-for="(item, index) in items" :key="index">
      <list-item
        :item="item"
        class="item"
        v-on:itemchanged="$emit('reloadlist')"
      />
   </div>
```

sorry to take up your time.

Comment: Can you please add some description of the underlying problem? That would be helpful for transferring this solution to other issues.